# Neo4j: Trying to find node with most relationships. Getting 'No Such Index' Error

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am playing with Neo4j and keep getting this error. What am I doing wrong.

My set of nodes looks like this

```
CREATE (p1:Person {name:"Hans"})
CREATE (p2:Person {name:"Anna"})
CREATE (p3:Person {name:"Klaus"})
CREATE (p4:Person {name:"Janna"})
CREATE (p5:Person {name:"Julia"})

CREATE (p1)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(p2)
CREATE (p1)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(p3)
CREATE (p1)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(p4)
CREATE (p1)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(p5)
CREATE (p2)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(p3)
CREATE (p3)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(p4)
```

I now want to find the person who has most friends

```
START n=node:Person('*:*')
MATCH (n)-[r]->(x)
RETURN n, COUNT(r)
ORDER BY COUNT(r) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Index `Person` does not exist
Neo.ClientError.Schema.NoSuchIndex
```

Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**

This query is working. I am still wondering, what the "No such Index" Error means

```
START n = node(*)
MATCH n<-[r:FRIENDS_WITH]->c
RETURN n.name, count(r) AS connections
ORDER BY connections DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran into one of our big API changes, we changed indexes in version 1.9 from the old start-syntax to labels and schema indexes:

Your query would look like this correctly:

```
MATCH (n:Person)-[r]->(x)
RETURN n, COUNT(r)
ORDER BY COUNT(r) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

if you want to look up people by name you should also create a schema index:

```
create index on :Person(name);
```

and then do

```
MATCH (n:Person)-[r]->(x)
WHERE n.name = "Hans"
RETURN n, COUNT(r)
ORDER BY COUNT(r) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks, great! I work with Cypher for 1 day now and I love it, very intuitive! One other question: My 'solution' I added to my question seems to return an aggregate or is distinct by name, not node. For example I have 2 Persons named Hans. My solution returns the sum of relationships of both Hans Persons. Your solution returns 2 Persons named Hans with the correct count each. Could you explain why?